# Unable to do git commit

Tags: git, github

I want to push a local project to a repository in Github. I have clone the repository locally and then I added the coding of the project into the src folder.

The problem is that when I try to do a commit, I get:

```
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   frontendPack2Fly (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Also, when I try to add it using git add frontendPack2Fly, I get this:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: src/frontendPack2Fly
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> src/frontendPack2Fly
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached src/frontendPack2Fly
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

Im new using Github and I have already created a repository with frontendPack2Fly folder, so I guess there is a problem with that. How can I solved this?

Comment: I think you have not created the git repository correctly. Can you please share link of your git repo?

Comment: https://github.com/ULL-TFGyMs-vblanco/TFG-2021-JesusNavarro.git

Comment: Please check if git folder is created in your folder? The repo seems private.

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: You can check in folder explorer and showing hidden files , it will be a folder named .git

Comment: "I get this" Well read what it says. It tells you just what the problem is and what to do about it.

Comment: There is a .git folder, so it is a git project

Comment: Have you tried git add .   This will add all files to local git repository

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any subfolders inside the main git repository has a folder named .git. Then delete that folder manually and try adding the files to git by using

```
git add .
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it worked for you